# Angular 8 : Wait for data from previous page to load then populate fields on current page

Tags: angular

In my application, I am fetching huge data in component-A and routing to component-B and passing some of the data to load few Graphs.
Since the data is huge fetching takes time and sometime the user may route to Component-B without the data and so error is thrown.
Can I wait on Component-B until all the data is fetched and show loading option on the page for the graphs until that data is fetched. Once data is fetched this graph will be populated.
Can I use web-workers to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Options that you can use:

1. You can save data in localstorage of browser and use from there. Don't pass the data. Pass the key to access data in localstorage. Keep compressed data in local storage.
2. Don't load all data at once. Load in chunks. Load when the chunk is required through manageable small HTTP requests. Some data engineering and data processing engineering would be required. You should load data required for component B separately if main dataset is huge.
3. Do not load data in Component A if it is not required to be used there. Load data only where it is actually required. Cache data locally to work across components.
4. Use [ngx-cacheable](https://github.com/angelnikolov/ngx-cacheable) to cache the responses. Or, cache the response through any other library.
5. Use store like redux to make data available for you. Requires a learning cycle.
6. Use [angular singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#:%7E:text=A%20singleton%20service%20is%20a%20service%20for%20which,to%20make%20a%20service%20a%20singleton%20in%20Angular%3A) to carry data for you.
7. Use reactive forms and [cache data with observables](https://tudip.com/blog-post/advanced-caching-with-rxjs/). The principles of web are to show only data for the visible part of screen at first load. Part which will show up in browser after scrolling can have data loaded later. Load data only when required for use on screen.
8. [Web Workers](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker) are for CPU intensive things. Fetching data may not be CPU intensive. [Service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) function as a network proxy. They intercept all outgoing HTTP requests made by the application and can choose how to respond to them. For example, they can query a local cache and deliver a cached response if one is available. Angular service worker can fetch this data from some cache (Redis, API cache). If you try to generate huge data at the time of call, generating it will take more time. Loading data to front end app generally gzips data for usage, and browsers know how to work with gzip formats.

Comment: Ok. I am relatively new to Angular. Is there any example that i can implement ?

Comment: All the links above and google search on these keywords will provide you multiple examples